# not getting string from the firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

```
    useEffect(()=>{

        fire.database().ref().child('/users/PKWNi2pt2mUfv097pTKwEtsnyOt2/preference/').
        on("value",(snapshot)=>{
            let item=snapshot.val()
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            setPrefer(item)
            }
    );})
```

[![][1]][1]

my db  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CvZT.png

I am expecting prefer to be

```
{"food":{"indian":false,"british":false,"american":false,
                                        "spanish":false,"chinese":false,"mexican":false,
                                        "japanese":false,"italian":false,"french":false}}
```

but I getting nothing.
Possible error would be in the on function.
Or function is working but giving me some other format of data, and need to convert it in some other format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I'd do it.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const preferenceRef = fire.database().ref(
    '/users/PKWNi2pt2mUfv097pTKwEtsnyOt2/preference/'
  );
  cosnt callback = (snapshot) => {
    setPrefer(snapshot.val());
  };
  preferenceRef.on('value', callback);
  
  return () => {
    preferenceRef.off('value', callback);
  };
);
}, [])
```

Comment: my code worked too but I was accessing it incorrectly